# Retrieve db records based on user role

Tags: laravel-5.5

I'm new in Laravel that's why I'm pretty sure that my ideas are wrong. To the point...

I'm building Laravel application.

What I have among other:

1. Users ( build in with Laravel auth with my custom fields )
2. Roles ( pivot, many to many )
3. Companies ( each user belongs to company ( many users can belong to one company ).
4. Locations ( each company has many Locations )

Now I'm in the middle of creating documents. For now it doesn't matter if user_id or company_id will be included in the document header.

What I need is to have ability to e.g.

- Show documents - *when I go to page with documents list with ADMIN role I will see all docs stored in db BUT when user with USER role goes to the same route ... he'll get the list of owned docs*
- location/edit/{id} - *prevent going to url with not mine id - this is simpler and I guess can be dealed using middleware*

I have 3 ideas:

1. Create somekind of FrontController and inside constructor run method that returns all users_ids ( or all companies_ids ) if user is ADMIN or when USER return only one id. All controller in the application then extends this FrontController
2. Create Service Class ( end up with many services depends on what model to retrieve ), method to get records from db calling repository with role parameter. Then in this method do the checks which ids should be used.
3. Maybe User somehow Laravel Policies and before() method. Nów I’m reading documentation but I really don't know how to use it in this case but I feel that this idea is also possible.

I feel that these ideas are "dirty". Can you, please, provide information how to implement this nicely with code snippet? I think this subject is very common and a lot of people will use this thred. I would be grateful for any tips.

Comment: This may or may not suffice, but in my case I displayed a list of comments, and to ensure only the person whose comment it belongs to can see the edit or delete links (which could in your case be a view details link etc) I added `@if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->id === $comment->user['id'])` which is finding a match between the currently logged in user and the comment id. If there is a match then the links show, if not they dont, as I placed this within a foreach loop.

Comment: yes your case suits to my 2nd bullet and for sure can be included in Laravel Gates with @can on view

Comment: glad I could help you a bit!

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be using local scopes.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#local-scopes

On your `Document` model define two scopes:

```
public function scopeBelongingToUser($query)
{
    return $query->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id);
}

// this is the same as doing on your User model
public function documents()
{
    $this->hasMany(Document::class);
}



public function scopeBelongingToAdmin($query)
{
    if (auth()->user()->roles->contains('admin') {
        return $query->select('*');
    }

    abort(403, 'Unauthorized');
}
```

Then you can use it later with:

```
Document::belongingToUser();

Document::belongingToAdmin();
```

Comment: What do you think about Laravel Policies and before method. I feel that this idea could also work but I cant figurę IT out how to code IT using Policy and e.g. before() method